# Find class's or property's Attribute and underline its parameters via roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

It needs to underline a string which contains russian characters.

I have written an extension for roslyn and in attributes for methods russian text is underlined, but for attributes for classes and properties i don't get it.

My code:
1) happens Initialize:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
   context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeRussianSymbols, SymbolKind.Parameter);
}
```

2) `AnalyzeRussianSymbols`:

```
public void AnalyzeRussianSymbols(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
         CompilationUnitSyntax root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)context.Symbol.Locations[0].SourceTree.GetRoot();

         AttributeListVirtualizationVisitor attributeArgument = new AttributeListVirtualizationVisitor();
         attributeArgument.Visit(root);

         CheckAttributes(attributeArgument, context);
}
```

3) Check attributes:

```
private void CheckAttributes(AttributeListVirtualizationVisitor attributeArgument, SymbolAnalysisContext context)
      {
         foreach (AttributeArgumentListSyntax attributes in attributeArgument.AttributeArgumentsList)
         {
            foreach (AttributeArgumentSyntax attr in attributes.Arguments)
            {
               SyntaxKind syntaxKind = attr.Expression?.Kind() ?? SyntaxKind.None;
               if(syntaxKind == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression && Regex.IsMatch(attr.NormalizeWhitespace().Expression.ToString(), "[а-яА-ЯёЁ]"))
               {
                  Diagnostic diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, attr.GetLocation(), attr);
                  context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
               }
            }
         }

      }
```

Finally, screenshot:
[image]

In red rectangle: Current string contains russian characters

I nedd a help!